# Validation.HasError does not trigger again if new error comes in while already true

Tags: wpf, tooltip, validation, idataerrorinfo, validationerror

I use MVVM and my object implement IDataErrorInfo.  When a property is set, I run custom validation methods and if the validation passes, I return String.empty, which sets Validation.HasError to false.  If the validation fails, Validation.HasError is set to true.  I have a style that I use for "required controls" (controls that will perform the validation) and set's the ToolTip of the control to whatever the error is like this:

```
<Style x:Key="RequiredControl" TargetType="{x:Type Control}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource ErrorConverter}, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the ErrorConverter:

```
public class ZynErrorContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var errors = value as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError>;
        if (errors == null) return "";

        return errors.Count > 0 ? errors[0].ErrorContent : "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is this: The user enters something invalid...and the Validation.HasError is set to true.  The tooltip updates as it is supposed to.  If the user attempts to correct the error, but enters a value that causes a different type of invalidation, the tooltip should show the new error string, but this doesn't happen.  The error shows as the same error from the first error.  I know why this happens (I think)...Because the Trigger is not triggered because the Validation.HasError never changes from True -> False -> True.

Does anyone have any experience with this or some advice as to how to force the trigger?

Comment: I have the same issue - did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No, never did. Still bugging me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the answer: [IDataErrorInfo With Multiple Error Messages for a Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494200/idataerrorinfo-with-multiple-error-messages-for-a-property/5513852#5513852)

Basically, you bind to the current item and use a ContentPresenter to display the error. It worked for my code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the proposal in my answer doesn't work - answer deleted now.

Comment: I still use the ToolTip but I use the CurrentItem now instead.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have figured this out.  The culprit is the use of the converter.
I was experiencing the same issue and the problem code snippet was:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                        Path=(Validation.Errors), 
                        Converter={StaticResource validationErrorsToStringConverter }}"/>
```

I change the snippet to :

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
```

and the issue was resolved.

Conclusion - Do not use a Converter.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this solution.

Comment: This solution could create unwanted debug logs, as described here: https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/binding-to-validationerrors0-without-creating-debug-spew/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what solved it was to remove the converter as Allan mentioned in his answer.

But instead of getting the `ErrorContent` by index such as, `Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent`, I used the [current record pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax#current-record-pointer) to get the current item.

Here is what it looks like in code:

```xml
<Setter Property="ToolTip" 
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}" />
```

More info can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.self?view=netframework-4.8