# IDataErrorInfo With Multiple Error Messages for a Property

Tags: wpf, idataerrorinfo

It appears someone else is having this issue:
[Validation.HasError does not trigger again if new error comes in while already true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606509/validation-haserror-does-not-trigger-again-if-new-error-comes-in-while-already-tr)

The Validation.Error is not updating with the latest error message.

It shows the previous error not the one that actually got called last.  When I log each return, the PropertyX is greater than or PropertyX is less than is returned, but it does not display that message in my tooltip.  It will displays "Required".

I also found that my converter for the tooltip does not get called when the PropertyX is greater than or PropertyX is less than is returned.

Here is the validation code:

```
    string this[string columnName] 
    {
        get
        {
            switch(columnName)
            {
                case "Property1":
                    int output;
                    if (true == string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property1))
                    {
                        return "Required";
                    } else if (true == int.TryParse(this.Property1, out output))
                    {
                        return "Invalid integer";
                    } else if (true == this.Property1Int.HasValue &&
                    true == this.Property2Int.HasValue)
                    {
                        if (this.Property1Int.Value < this.Property2Int.Value)
                        {
                            return "Property2 is greater than Property1";
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                case "Property2":
                    int output;
                    if (true == string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Property2))
                    {
                        return "Required";
                    } else if (true == int.TryParse(this.Property2, out output))
                    {
                        return "Invalid integer";
                    } else if (true == this.Property1Int.HasValue &&
                    true == this.Property2Int.HasValue)
                    {
                        if (this.Property2Int.Value > this.Property1Int.Value)
                        {
                            return "Property2 is greater than Property1";
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            };

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

What is going on?

Comment: Probably it is impossible, because if it was allowed as it is in Silverlight, we would have a method which returns IEnumerable and not a single string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation.HasError does not trigger again if new error comes in while already true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606509/validation-haserror-does-not-trigger-again-if-new-error-comes-in-while-already-tr)

Comment: Can you add how you bind this error? Is it same as duplicate one?

Comment: Yeah I bind the same way with the Validation.HasError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using converter as in other question, them I'm prety sure its not the best way to do things. Especialy in dynamic enviorment like WPF.

So I would recomend binding to `(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem` directly instead of using converter as described here:

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/binding-to-validationerrors0-without-creating-debug-spew/

Comment: That was the path I started to go down when I realized the HasError was updating the trigger.  Too bad most people use the trigger instead of this way.  It would prevent some heartache with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If your binding is using a converter, then this problem could be solved by removing the converter and changing the binding.

For example, say that the XAML looks like the following:

```xml
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}" />
```

Then by updating the code to the following, you will bypass the converter:

```xml
<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}" />
```

Read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.self?view=netframework-4.8